# Equivalent Definition of a Tree Graph Theory: Restriction for Being Connected?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I was looking at some [equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) of a tree in graph theory and one is the following where we let $G$ be an undirected graph:

$G$ is a tree iff $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges where $n$ denotes the number of vertices in $G$.

My question is why  is there the restriction that $G$ is connected here? Isn't it true that $G$ is a tree iff $|E(G)|=|V(G)|-1$? I thought $|E(G)|=|V(G)|-1$ implies that $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $|E|=|V|-1$, not $|V|=|E|-1$.

You can have a graph with four vertices, three of which are conected with three edges but isolated from the remaining one. This graph clearly complies with $|E|=|V|-1$, but is not connected.

Comment: Sorry about the $|E|=|V|-1$ thing. I get what you mean. Do you know if it would be true for graphs without isolated vertices?

Comment: I'm sure it does in that case. I appreciate your help!